# Issue with Hive while Storing Streaming Data

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-kafka

I have a Kafka Streaming Consumer job which stores the data in Hive table.
The issue is that sometimes the job fails due to Hive and has to be restarted again.
This is happening with all the streaming consumer jobs which are trying to access Hive.
Not able to trace the reason.
Appreciate your suggestions.

Below is the high level error log

```
INFO ApplicationMaster: Starting the user application in a separate Thread
INFO ApplicationMaster: Waiting for spark context initialization...
WARN SparkConf: The configuration key 'spark.yarn.applicationMaster.waitTries' has been deprecated as of Spark 1.3 and may be removed in the future. Please use the new key 'spark.yarn.am.waitTime' instead.
INFO metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://<server1:port1>
WARN metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
INFO metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://<server1:port1>
WARN metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
INFO metastore: Waiting 1 seconds before next connection attempt.
INFO metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://<server2:port1>
WARN metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
INFO metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://<server1:port1>
WARN metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
INFO metastore: Waiting 1 seconds before next connection attempt.
INFO metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://<server2:port1>
WARN metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
INFO metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://<server1:port1>
WARN metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
INFO metastore: Waiting 1 seconds before next connection attempt.
WARN Hive: Failed to access metastore. This class should not accessed in runtime.
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: MetaException(message:Could not connect to meta store using any of the URIs provided. Most recent failure: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Peer indicated failure: DIGEST-MD5: IO error acquiring password

 INFO metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://<server2:port1>
 WARN metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
 INFO metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://<server1:port1>
 WARN metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
 INFO metastore: Waiting 1 seconds before next connection attempt.
 INFO metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://<server2:port1>
 WARN metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
 INFO metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://<server1:port1>
 WARN metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
 INFO metastore: Waiting 1 seconds before next connection attempt.
 INFO metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://<server2:port1>
 WARN metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
 INFO metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://<server1:port1>
 WARN metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
 INFO metastore: Waiting 1 seconds before next connection attempt.
 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: MetaException(message:Could not connect to meta store using any of the URIs provided. Most recent failure: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Peer indicated failure: DIGEST-MD5: IO error acquiring password
```

Comment: Personally, I would suggest NiFi or Kafka Connect for writing to HDFS/Hive. Less (actually none) Spark code to write/maintain. But, seems like you might want to setup a load-balanced HiveServer, if it is crashing (look at the Hive logs, not your Spark logs)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion..Can you please clarify when you Hive logs

Comment: On your Hive Server and Metastore server, there will be log files for these processes. That is something you will need to show us. It those processes are down, then you would see a failure to connect, such as above

Comment: When i checked the Hive logs, it seems the Hive is never down when the applications are failing. Also another thing i see in the above logs that it just tries for 3 times waiting for 1 sec each time. Currently in Hive below 2 properties are set like :      hive.metastore.client.connect.retry.delay = 5s
and hive.metastore.client.socket.timeout = 1800s.. Do you think changing these values will help. Also let me know what will be an optimum value

Comment: I am not sure. I haven't worked with configuring Hive is years